# How can I clone an existing table schema to create a new empty table with the same structure, using C#?

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm connecting to an SQL Server 2008 database.

Using C#, I'd like to create a new table, with a name specified by me, which looks exactly like an existing table in that database.  There are no foreign keys involved.

I have code like

```
DataTable table = con.GetSchema("Tables");
foreach (System.Data.DataRow row in table.Rows)
{
    foreach (System.Data.DataColumn col in table.Columns)
```

But it doesn't get me very far.  Do I really need to iterate over all the tables myself?  Even if I identify the `DataTable` how do I clone it?  I looked at `DataTable.Clone` but I can't see how to set a new name and create that table on the database.

Comment: Nothing that compiles!  I've been wading through MSDN documentation for the the last hour, trying things like the code pasted above...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SMO ([Server Management Objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162169.aspx)) has a great deal of table scripting abilities. I would start there.

This [article](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/ben_miller/archive/2007/10/03/table-scripting-with-smo-part-1.aspx) might help get you started.

If you want to avoid SMO, you can do it via a SQLDataReader, as follows (or something close to this):

```
using (SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    using (SqlCommand cmd = cnn.CreateCommand())
    {
       cmd.CommandText = "Execute some SQL Select here. Doesn't matter what. We just need a reference to the table.";
       cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
       cnn.Open();
       using (SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.KeyInfo))
       {
          schema = rdr.GetSchemaTable();
       }
    cnn.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there way to avoid SMO?  I'm trying to avoid dependencies since my app is one of the first things that a new user will run.  I seem to recall that SMO needs to be installed via the SQL Server MSI?

Comment: @Ben - I've updated my answer to include some code which should allow you to read a target table schema. You then should be able to create a new table based on that.